# Убрать static из всех классов в адаптере RecyclerView

Tags: android

Подскажите пожалуйста, как убрать из трех классов `static` (сделать их все  не статическими), чтобы не было ошибки в методе `load_image_and_namePoints()` в строке

```
sectionModelArrayList.add(new SectionRecyclerViewAdapter.SectionModel("Section " + i, itemArrayList)); ?
```

Вот три класса с `static`(один вложенный внизу):

```
 public static class ItemRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemRecyclerViewAdapter.ItemViewHolder> {

    class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView itemLabel;
        private ImageView iv_images_points; // все изображения в секциях

        public ItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemLabel = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_label);
            iv_images_points = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_images_points);
        }
    }

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<String> arrayList;

    public ItemRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> arrayList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        final View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.z_maket_item_rv_gallery_2, parent, false);

        // с ней ползет чуть вверх все(( view.setMinimumHeight((int) (120 * context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density));// чтобы быстрее загружалось без скачков
        //для квадратного вида, подгоняем высоту по ширине
        ViewTreeObserver vto = view.getViewTreeObserver();
        vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                view.setMinimumHeight(view.getWidth());
            }
        });

        return new ItemViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.itemLabel.setText(arrayList.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }


}


//2:  (адаптер Секции )

public static class SectionRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SectionRecyclerViewAdapter.SectionViewHolder> {


    class SectionViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView sectionLabel, showAllButton;
        private RecyclerView itemRecyclerView;

        public SectionViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            sectionLabel = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            showAllButton = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.section_show_all_button);
            itemRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_recycler_view);
        }
    }

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<SectionModel> sectionModelArrayList;

    public SectionRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SectionModel> sectionModelArrayList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.sectionModelArrayList = sectionModelArrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public SectionViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.z_maket_item_rv_gallery_2_sections, parent, false);
        return new SectionViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(SectionViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final SectionModel sectionModel = sectionModelArrayList.get(position);
        holder.sectionLabel.setText(sectionModel.getSectionLabel());

        //recycler view for items
        holder.itemRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        holder.itemRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

    /* set layout manager on basis of recyclerview enum type */

        GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(context, 3);
        holder.itemRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);


        ItemRecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new ItemRecyclerViewAdapter(context, sectionModel.getItemArrayList());
        holder.itemRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        //show toast on click of show all button
        holder.showAllButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "You clicked on Show All of : " + sectionModel.getSectionLabel(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return sectionModelArrayList.size();
    }



    //отдельный класс секции
    public static class SectionModel {
        private String sectionLabel;
        private ArrayList<String> itemArrayList;

        public SectionModel(String sectionLabel, ArrayList<String> itemArrayList) {
            this.sectionLabel = sectionLabel;
            this.itemArrayList = itemArrayList;
        }

        public String getSectionLabel() {
            return sectionLabel;
        }

        public ArrayList<String> getItemArrayList() {
            return itemArrayList;
        }
    }

}
```

А в этом методе эту строку -

```
sectionModelArrayList.add(new SectionRecyclerViewAdapter.SectionModel("Section " + i, itemArrayList));
```

- подчеркивает красным, если везде убрать `static`:

  ```
  public void load_image_and_namePoints(){
  RecyclerView recyclerView;
  recyclerView = (RecyclerView)  mapsActivity.findViewById(R.id.gallery_rv_2);
  recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
  LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new   LinearLayoutManager(mapsActivity);
  recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

  ArrayList<SectionRecyclerViewAdapter.SectionModel>  sectionModelArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
  //for loop for sections
  for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
      ArrayList<String> itemArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
      //for loop for items
      for (int j = 1; j <= 7; j++) {
          itemArrayList.add("Item " + j);
      }

      //add the section and items to array list
      sectionModelArrayList.add(new   SectionRecyclerViewAdapter.SectionModel("Section " + i, itemArrayList));
  }

  SectionRecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new   SectionRecyclerViewAdapter(mapsActivity, sectionModelArrayList);
  recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
  ```

  }

Не могу сообразить, что где подправить..

Comment: **1 вариант:** вынести класс в отдельный файл. **2 вариант:** создавать его экземпляры (`new`) только внутри класса, в котором он объявлен. Тогда модификатор `stastic` не понадобится.

Comment: Спасибо, а со вторым вариантом можете помочь? Вот я убрал все модификаторы static, и сразу подчеркивает красным -  sectionModelArrayList.add(new SectionRecyclerViewAdapter.SectionModel("Section " + i, itemArrayList));  в методе load_image_and_namePoints().. Как тут правильно написать?

Comment: Правильно написать этот код можно только внутри класса `SectionRecyclerViewAdapter`. В другом классе создать экземпляр `SectionModel` нельзя. А чем, собственно, Вам не нравится `static`?

Comment: Да я использую другие методы и поля из других классов в onBindViewHolder и тд, не удобно немного, надо их тоже тогда статическими делать. А так без static никаких проблем..

Comment: Но из самой модели (`SectionModel`) Вы ведь ничего не вызываете - можно присвоить ей самостоятельность (`static`).

Comment: Если его вынести класс отдельно и оставить static, то ошибки в методе load_image_and_namePoints().. Я не могу разобраться как там правильно написать.. Если все вложить в класс SectionRecyclerViewAdapter и убрать static, то тоже в методе load_image_and_namePoints() подчеркивает красным строку sectionModelArrayList.add(new SectionRecyclerViewAdapter.SectionModel("Section " + i, itemArrayList))  Не могу понять как надо написать. Вроде тут исправить-то надо несколько строчек..

Comment: Так а тут, чтобы избавиться от static, много чего переделывать надо?